# Does Git Rebase Master affect the local master branch?

Tags: git

Here is my process:

```sh
git checkout featureBranch
# make changes on this branch, add, commit
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge featureBranch
```

Does this affect my master branch permanently, so that it's history includes that of feature branch? How can I get rid of this or undo a git rebase once it's already been done?

Answer (score 4):

A rebase affects the branch you're rebasing and not the branch onto which you're rebasing.  So in this case, it affects `featureBranch`, but not `master`.  However, merging your feature branch into `master` does affect `master`, and then the history of `master` contains all the commits that were in `master` before, as well as those in `featureBranch`; that's pretty much the goal of a merge: to incorporate changes from both branches.

If you are unhappy with a rebase or merge, you can look at the reflog for that branch by running something like `git reflog master`.  This will show all the states that branch has been in, and when your working tree is clean, you can run `git reset --hard COMMIT-ID`.  That will roll that branch back to where you were before and destroy any changes in your working tree.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `git reflog master`